# Kernel killing java process

Tags: java, tomcat

We have three Ubuntu 12.04 boxes that are load balanced behind nginx.  We originally installed tomcat7 using apt-get but ran into an issue where I believe the kernel is killing the java process due to OOM.  I switched to the latest tomcat7 distribution and installed it manually.  Same result.

We have a swap file enabled.  I originally had swapiness set to 0 per hosted provider's recommendation.  I switched to swapiness of 60.  It looks like it is still happening.

Here is what I see in the syslog:

```
Feb  8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280798] select 1 (init), adj 0, size 371, to kill    
Feb  8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280813] select 425 (rsyslogd), adj 0, size 497, to kill    
Feb  8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280827] select 18905 (bash), adj 0, size 1568, to kill    
Feb  8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280831] select 28556 (java), adj 0, size 63276, to kill    
Feb  8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280837] send sigkill to 28556 (java), adj 0, size 63276
```

System Info:

- 512MB RAM
- 512MB swapfile enabled.
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
- apache-tomcat-7.0.50
- Java Memory set with -Xmx64m

I can see memory usage going up and down with the java process.  I see garbage collection happening.  I will monitor usage and see RAM drop to <5MB and a garbage collection will happen returning memory back up to greater than 100MB free.

No errors occuring in Tomcat7.  The process is just killed at least once a day by the linux kernel.

Comment: need more data to stand a chance of answering this if it's not an "I have an issue and a solution, so I'm using stackexchange as a scratchpad" type of thing.

Comment: Ok, what data would you like me to post?  These are new installs.  Nothing else installed on the systems.  So Ubuntu 12.04, tomcat7, openjdk, and our deployed app in tomcat.  My big thing is the only reason I know the kernel would kill a process in this is way is due to out of memory

Comment: How you know that is the kernel killing due OOM it and not tomcat?

Comment: Because the syslog indicates the following:   


Feb 8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280831] select 28556 (java), adj 0, size 63276, to kill



Feb 8 06:35:38 processor1 kernel: [658920.280837] send sigkill to 28556 (java), adj 0, size 63276



Additionally, when initially investigating, we turned tomcat7 logging up to the max and we got zero output indicating any issues.  We would see a request being processed fine and them nothing.  So I started looking for why the process was dying and I found that the kernel is sending the sigkill command to the java process.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some situations when the OOM-killer kicked in, but the log made by the OOM-killer was nothing like in your question. So I thought something is changed in the OOM-killer in a newer kernel version, so I made a livegrep for the phrase *"send sigkill to"*, [here is the result](http://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=send+sigkill+to). As you can see this kind of log is not coming from the OOM-killer but from Android's lowmemory-killer. It is strange.

Knowing the source of the problem I very soon found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1206891) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1235161) bugreport.  These explain the situation and looks like this bug was fixed in the saucy kernel, but looks like it wasn't fixed in the precise kernel.

I don't know when this will be fixed in your particular precise kernel (which I think is 3.8), but you can update your 12.04 installation to the kernel of 13.10 by installing the [hardware enablement packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) with

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy
```

Of course if you don't use the `xserver` (no GUI) on your machine, then only install the newer kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing.  Dumbfounding but amazing.  I can't say this will fix the issue but I will be discussing with coworker whether we want to build out new 13.10 boxes or actually upgrade our existing boxes to 13.10.

Comment: @user246046 If you need longterm support you shouldn't switch to 13.10. To solve this problem it must be enough to just switch to the newer kernel with the command I gave in my answer. Upgrading the kernel shouldn't normally cause any problems. Or if you want a new install, you can install 12.04.4 which already comes with the newer kernel present in 13.10.

Comment: Then this might not be the issue.  My current ubuntu version is 12.04.4.

Comment: @user246046 What is the output of `uname -r`? 12.04.4 was released 3 days ago. So if you not installed your ubuntu in the last 3 days you definitely have the older kernel. The `lsb_release -a` output will show 12.04.4 for a fully upgraded 12.04, even if it has an older kernel, even for a 3.2 kernel.

Comment: It is 3.8.0-29-generic so it is a version impacted.  I did use the lsb_release -a and that is why I thought I had 12.04.4.  Thanks